# How to pass value to text box through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using the bootstrap framework to call a modal dialog- and I'm trying to pass it a unique value from a mysql table depending on the row clicked.

I have the code working to the point where it will pass the value to the dialog, but i can't get it to display in a text box. The h3 displays it in a header for now.

Heres a link to the working code.
http://jsfiddle.net/ZEpLV/14/

Here's what my code look like:

```
<div id="com" class="modal hide fade in" style="display: none; ">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
            <h4>Server ID:<h3>PLace for your id</h3>

    <div class="modal-body">
        <h4>Text in a modal</h4>
        <input value="" type="text" name="id" Value="">
        <p>You can add some text here.</p>              
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Call to action</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
    </div>
    <script>

    $(".modal-toggler").click(function(){
    var _id = $(this).attr("id");
    $("#com h3").text(_id);
    $("#com").show();
    return false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: The h3 displays it in a heading in the dialog. I can put any value in and it will display in that field. For example p would display it inside the p tag. Although i can't seem to get this to work for a text box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For **inputs** you need to use `.val()` instead of `.text()`

```
$("#com input").val(_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Give an Id to text filed and use id of text field and   `.val()`

```
$("#text").val(_id);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/chauhangs/ZEpLV/15/

```
 $(".modal-toggler").click(function(){
   var _id = $(this).attr("id");
   $("#com h3").text(_id);
   $("#text").val(_id);
   $("#com").show();
   return false;
});
```